# What is the point of stacking favorite notifications?

Tags: discussion, favorites-notifications

I noticed I have more notifications than favorites, which means that the notifications are stacked (in other words, there can be more than 1 notification per question).

[image]

Here is my reasoning:

- **Why do they add up?**, I don't know where is the benefit of knowing that some of the questions had multiple changes *if we are not able to see which questions had how many changes*

Since we don't know what questions had what amount of changes, the amount of notifications is just a meaningless number that don't help us too much. Here are some possible solutions:

- Add a max of 1 notification per question
- Keep the same number, but allow us to see how many new changes there were on every question

Comment: I've wondered about this, too.  It's, in general, a sort of vague and confusing number.

Comment: "just a meaningless number" - no it's not. You've demonstrated that you *do* know its meaning. You might well find it *useless*, but that's your opinion. What, if any, *damage* does it do, that it should be removed?

Answer (score 4):

Good and valid point - there is no point in that. Knowing how many updates were made to your favorite posts is not that helpful.

More than that - in my opinion, it is enough to know just "There is a change in your favorites list" so I would be happy to have only a bright yellow star appear there instead of a number:

[image: favorite changes with a star]

Answer (score -7):

Yes you have **7** (seven) Favortites, **but** they were updated a total of **20** (count them -- twenty) times since you last looked at that tab.

The number on top is the total number of updates for all the yellow tinted favorites.

And ***of course*** we know which questions had which number of updates, just go to the `/timeline` on any post and you shall see

Comment: I know, but I want to discus how is that number helpful in any way if we don't know how many times a post had changed

Comment: @ajax333221 of course you know how many times the post has changes. Thats what the `timeline` and `revisions` pages are for!