# Why am I notified of 87 new favorite questions when I only have five favorites?

Tags: support, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

Imagine my surprise to go looking at my user profile on mSO and find out that I've somehow added 87 new favorite questions. Yet, upon looking at the favorites tab, I see only five favorites.

What's going on here?

[image: 87 new favorites]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137767/what-is-the-point-of-stacking-favorite-notifications Basically, they are 87 notifications. Not 87 favourites

Comment: Might that be 87 updates to your favourite questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that means there has been a total of 87 different updates across all your favorited questions.

Comment: That may be, though I can't imagine how such a number would be remotely useful.

Comment: useful who knows but easy to code, sure. One of your facves has a change, just bump the number, no need to check if it's one that changed before and is already counted