# Notifications from favorite posts

Tags: feature-request, community

Why is there not yet a solution for notifications from favorite posts, because I think it's a great feature most people wanted?

I think it just completes the favourite option. Why is it taking too long for this feature? Are there any semantic problems? What is the status of this feature?

Comment: somewhat [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137767/what-is-the-point-of-stacking-favorite-notifications) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145252/how-can-i-receive-notifications-about-favorite-questions)