# How to receive updates on favourited questions?

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks

Is there a way in which one can receive updates on favourited questions?

I'm not sure if such a feature is available. When another user asks a good question, it would be nice to keep track of the answers to that question.

Comment: you can't, that feature isn't implemented, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268413/notifications-from-favorite-posts

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work/53580#53580 This is the most recent post about this.

Comment: If this or something similar gets implemented, I do hope they make the notifications optional. I have favorited so many questions in my home site I lost track of them. And I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Rubisco there used to be envelope that lit up every time there was new activity in a favourite question, but it was removed and replaced with the notifications system we have these days. I doubt SE will revert the wheel and implement such a thing again, so you're safe.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox